# CSS transition width of line to center

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am learning about CSS transitions and I'm trying to make 3 offset lines reduce width to their respective center points. Right now the width transition is occurring to the left and not the center.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w793sps6/6/).

How can I transition the width of each line their respective center points?

The code:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('lines')

div.addEventListener('click', function() {
 var className = div.getAttribute("class");

 if (className != 'open') {
  div.className = 'open';
 } else {
  div.className = '';
 }
})
```

```css
#lines {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
#lines span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #d3531a;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: width .25s ease-in-out;
}
#lines span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
#lines span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 18px;
  left: 18px;
}
#lines span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 36px;
  left: 36px;
}

#lines.open span {
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lines">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your scss so your spans aren't showing up. Missing a semicolon. Be sure to check that your demo works before posting. Ideally you wouldn't post SCSS though, just post the rendered CSS. https://jsfiddle.net/w793sps6/3/

Comment: That's weird, the spans are appearing in the fiddle

Comment: Not in https://jsfiddle.net/w793sps6/1/ you're missing a semicolon so the scss doesn't compile.

Comment: Nice catch thanks, I updated it and fixed the code snippet here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform: scale()` instead of `width` and the `transform-origin` will  be the center by default.

```js
const div = document.getElementById('lines')

div.addEventListener('click', function() {
 var className = div.getAttribute("class");

 if (className != 'open') {
  div.className = 'open';
 } else {
  div.className = '';
 }
})
```

```css
#lines {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
#lines span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #d3531a;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
}
#lines span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
#lines span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 18px;
  left: 18px;
}
#lines span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 36px;
  left: 36px;
}

#lines.open span {
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="lines">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I found that in order to use `transform: scaleX(0);` on an active element, I needed to use `transform: scaleX(1);` on the non active element or else the animation causes the element to abruptly disappear.