# CSS Transition Width From Center

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I want my container to open up from the center to the specified width when on hover of the parent.

The problem is that I can't get it to not open up from the left. I want it to work similarly to [this situation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669337/css-transition-width-of-line-to-center).

If possible, I'd like the animation for the corners of the container to activate after it has done it's first animation.

```css
body {
  background: #4e4e4e;
}

#music {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

#music:hover {
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#music img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#music:hover .music-container {
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  height: 23px;
  width: 210px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.music-container {
  height: 23px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: -85px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="music">
  <center>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cgIfJId.gif" />
  </center>
  <div class="music-container">
    <center>
      <font color="white" size="1">
        jsfiddle can't load my music lol
      </font>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `transform` property over-here to increase width from center for `.music-container`,

```css
body {
  background: #4e4e4e;
}

#music {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

#music:hover {
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#music img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#music:hover .music-container {
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  height: 23px;
  width: 210px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.music-container {
  height: 23px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-top: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  left: 50%; /*Add this*/
  transform: translate(-50%, 0); /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<div id="music">
  <center>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cgIfJId.gif" />
  </center>
  <div class="music-container">
    <center>
      <font color="white" size="1">
        jsfiddle can't load my music lol
      </font>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works the way I want it to, but there is one problem. The flash embed (music player) doesn't properly work. I can't interact with the flash unless I either right and left click over a button or spam that button. You can see that problem in action [here](https://a.uguu.se/f6rPcVjduEUv.html).

Comment: @Jona Your browser might be blocking that flash from running, it works fine on my browser as I click audio plays. If you using chrome you can allow flash by going in setting/content/flash then allow flash on following url.

Comment: I am using Firefox and it is definitely not blocking flash, and I have tested this with my previous code and it works fine. But with this CSS animation, it won't let me click any of the buttons unless I do the steps I stated previous. Perhaps the CSS animation is causing the flash to not work properly? [I made a gif to demonstrate my isssue](https://i.imgur.com/f7vz5rN.gif).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that transitioning `transform: scale` instead of `width`.

```css
body {
  background: #4e4e4e;
}

#music {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

#music:hover {
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#music img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#music:hover .music-container {
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  height: 23px;
  width: 210px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.music-container {
  height: 23px;
  width: 210px;
  transform: scale(0);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: -85px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="music">
  <center>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cgIfJId.gif" />
  </center>
  <div class="music-container">
    <center>
      <font color="white" size="1">
        jsfiddle can't load my music lol
      </font>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this css instead of `left: calc(50% - 50px);` I add this css in `#music` id for center. and also add and change in css for hover please check this.

```
#music {  
 left:0;
 right:0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
#music:hover .music-container {   
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}    
.music-container {
  height: 23px;
  width: 210px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: -85px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  left:0;
  right:0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #4e4e4e;
}

#music {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

#music:hover {
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

#music img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#music:hover .music-container {   
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.music-container {
  height: 23px;
  width: 210px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: -85px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  left:0;
  right:0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="music">
  <center>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cgIfJId.gif" />
  </center>
  <div class="music-container">
    <center>
      <font color="white" size="1">
        jsfiddle can't load my music lol
      </font>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following snippet, the middle box `.strip` is an `inline-block` so it 'grows' from center...

```css
.holder{
  width       : 500px;
  margin      : 0px auto;
  text-align  : center;
  font-family : arial;
}

.button{
  display       : inline-block;
  padding       : 3px;
  background    : #333;
  color         : #fff;
  border-radius : 3px;
  cursor        : pointer;
}

.hover:hover .strip{
  width : 100px;
}

.padd{ padding:3px; }

.strip{
  box-sizing    : border-box;
  border-radius : 3px;
  margin-top    : 5px;
  width         : 0px;
  display       : inline-block;
  overflow      : hidden;
  white-space   : nowrap;
  transition    : all 0.3s ease-out;
  background    : #333;
  color         : #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="hover">
  <div class="button">Hover Me</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="strip">
    <div class="padd">Some Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```