# Flash Not Working Properly With Transform:Translate Property

Tags: html, css, flash

I was trying to figure out how to center my CSS transition animation with width only; [which was solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509600/css-transition-width-from-center/).

The [music player](https://www.sheepproductions.com/billy/) that I am using is acting strangely with the `tranform:translate` property. Before I implemented the `transform:translate` property, the music player worked correctly.

**Problem** : But when I started using it **I couldn't click any of the buttons** unless I either spammed them or right clicked into a menu then left clicked them; which you can see here : [GIF example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eal7S.gif).

[image]

You can view this issue in action at : [this demo page](https://a.uguu.se/z1Wyq1kB0AEx.html).

This is my code (used at demo page) :

**CSS** code :

```
body {
      background-color: black;
    }

    #music {
      position: absolute;
      top: 140px;
      left: 155px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid white;
      background-color: #000;
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
      transition: all 0.8s ease;
    }

    #music:hover {
      -moz-border-radius: 100px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
      border-radius: 100px;
    }

    #music img {
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    #music:hover .music-container {
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      height: 23px;
      width: 210px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      opacity: 1;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #000;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
      transition: all 0.8s ease;
    }

    .music-container {
      height: 23px;
      width: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #000;
      border: 1px solid white;
      margin-top: 8px;
      overflow: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }
```

**HTML** code :

```
    <div id="music">
      <center>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cgIfJId.gif" />
      </center>
      <div class="music-container">
        <center>
          <font size="1" color="white">
            Music Player not supported. See link in SO to view.
          </font>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Enable Flash in your browser, click the icon, audio player expands and starts playing music. Tested in Chrome/Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. Did you watch the gif?

Comment: Not obvious. All I see is a _wall of text_. I will edit the post for clarity...

Comment: PS: I tested In Chrome (Windows PC) and it works 100% fine (play, stop, next track... all buttons work). What browsers is this not working on?

Comment: I am using this on Firefox. I haven't had any problems with any CSS animation in this browser so far, so I am not sure what the issue is.